# error in compile PHP with visual studio 2012

Tags: php, c++, c, visual-studio-2012

i compile php 5.6 with visual studio 2012 like this link: [Build your own PHP on Windows](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild)
but these errors was displayed:

```
c:\php-sdk-binary-tools-20110915\phpdev\vc11\x86\php-5.6.0-src\zend\zend_globals_macros.h(35) : warning C4028: formal parameter 1 different from declaration
Zend\zend_indent.c(72) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
zend_ini.c
zend_ini_parser.c
Zend/zend_ini_parser.c(399) : warning C4028: formal parameter 1 different from declaration
Zend/zend_ini_parser.c(1548) : error C2198: 'ini_lex' : too few arguments for call
Zend/zend_ini_parser.y(285) : error C2065: 'tsrm_ls' : undeclared identifier
Zend/zend_ini_parser.y(285) : warning C4022: 'function through pointer' : pointer mismatch for actual parameter 6
Zend/zend_ini_parser.y(292) : error C2065: 'tsrm_ls' : undeclared identifier
Zend/zend_ini_parser.y(292) : warning C4022: 'function through pointer' : pointer mismatch for actual parameter 6
Zend/zend_ini_parser.y(300) : error C2065: 'tsrm_ls' : undeclared identifier
Zend/zend_ini_parser.y(300) : warning C4022: 'function through pointer' : pointer mismatch for actual parameter 6
Zend/zend_ini_parser.y(305) : error C2065: 'tsrm_ls' : undeclared identifier
Zend/zend_ini_parser.y(305) : warning C4022: 'function through pointer' : pointer mismatch for actual parameter 6
Zend/zend_ini_parser.y(361) : error C2065: 'tsrm_ls' : undeclared identifier
Zend/zend_ini_parser.y(361) : warning C4022: 'zend_ini_get_var' : pointer mismatch for actual parameter 3
Zend/zend_ini_parser.y(373) : error C2065: 'tsrm_ls' : undeclared identifier
Zend/zend_ini_parser.y(373) : warning C4022: 'zend_ini_get_constant' : pointer mismatch for actual parameter 3
Zend/zend_ini_parser.c(1993) : warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\vs 11.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Comment: The error messages refer to specific source files with line numbers.  Inspect the code at the referenced line to see what it is objecting to. The diagnostics themselves are mostly self explanatory.  Start with the first error, fix it and try again - often one error can cause multiple diagnostics such as a missing header file or an include path to the wrong version.  I am not sure what the .y files are, but probably need to force C rather than C++ compilation possibly.

Comment: Please consider the guidelines to provide a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @jack regarding the .y extension, I appreciate it is not your file, but it is your build.  All I am pointing out is that Visual Studio chooses C or C++ compilation based on the filename extension, and it may default to C++ for unknown extensions.  I am not saying that is happening, just that you should check.

Comment: @jack Regarding the error messages, the compiler is clearly not "wrong".  It is simply working from different information than you think it is, or which you intended.  As it is we cannot help without downloading the project and trying it for ourselves.  You could save everyone the trouble by including the code that the diagnostic refers to, so we can see what it is complaining about.

Comment: Where did you get the source for 5.6? It is no longer supported, and is not available via the links in the article.  It's use is probably I'll advised in any event.